# Generate highlighted snippets in Solr for PDFs

Tags: solr

I'm new to solr. I've set up a solr server and have indexed a few thousand PDFs. I am trying to query solr via the rest API in a PHP page. I am trying to build something similar to the solritas interface included in the tutorial (solrserver/browse), but I don't know how to generate highlighted snippets. I found in the documentation "hl" is a query parameter and is by default set to false.

When I get `http://solrserver/?q=search+term&hl=true` I get back a response with a hightlighting section, but it only contains the document IDs, no generated snippets.

I am using the tutorial provided schema and config for solr 4.2.1. I believe that the configuration is fine because solritas is able to display highlighted snippets using the same indexed data. I've tried seeing how solritas is built but it's separated out in .vm template files and I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for yet.

I can see the full text of the PDF in the doc->content area, so it is stored. I think I just don't understand the proper way to generate snippets! Can someone please help!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest, you should try using hl.fl parameter. So your query should be something like this:

**?q=search+term&hl=true&hl.fl=field1,field2,field3**

Where field1, field2 and field3 are three source fields you would like to generate highlights.

In your case, if the field name you want to use for highlighting is content, your query can be:

**?q=search+term&hl=true&hl.fl=content**

More details: http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Highlighting

With highlighting, you can even specify fragment size, HTML tags around highlighted text etc...

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks!! Also the lucidworks documentation is much more friendly than the solr wiki. Thank you!

Comment: Haha... thats true. Am glad my answer helped you.